# using multiple curly braces in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call the loadData function which is working in the component call. The information also renders correctly on screen. But when I add {this.loadData()} inside the render() it will not work.

```
I get Syntax error: C:/Users/jokar38/workspace/react/moviedb/src/App.jsx: Unexpected token, expected , (40:8)

componentDidMount() {
      console.log('GrandChild did mount.');

      this.loadData()
    }
render() {
      const { data } = this.state;
      return (
        <ul>
          // if data not loaded null will render nothing
          // if data is not null, we iterate data.results with map
          { data && data.results.map(function (film, index) {
            // film is an object, just one or more properties to render
            return <li key={ index }>{ film.display_title }</li>; 
          }) };
        </ul>
        {this.loadData()} <---------- This won't work
      );
    }
```

Comment: What does this.loadData() do? If it returns something to render then probably yonasstephen's answer is the one you need. However, if you are getting some data and maybe using `this.setState`, then you shouldn't be using that method in the render method, especially in the return statement.

Comment: is this .loadData returning jsx tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is render method can only return a single root node. So what you can do is to wrap your elements inside another `<div>` as such:

```
componentDidMount() {
   console.log('GrandChild did mount.');
   this.loadData()
}

render() {
   const { data } = this.state;
   return (
     <div>
        <ul>
           { data && data.results.map(function (film, index) {
               return <li key={ index }>{ film.display_title }</li>; 
           }) };
        </ul>
        {this.loadData()}
     </div>
   );
}
```

Alternatively if you use **React 16** you could [return an array from render method](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10294). On a side note, if `loadData()` does not return any components, I suggest you put it somewhere else like `componentDidMount`.